# How to filter a string position inside an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm looking to filter an array by the month and year which found on position 3 of the row
where the dates are *dd/mm/yyy*.

array generated from a google sheets:

> [[1, 134, DIOGO, 03/**12**/**2019**, ggggg, 2], [2, 131, ALEISIO, 13/**11**/**2019**, ggg, 33], [3, 134, DIOGO, 25/**11**/**2019**, gggg, 2], [4, 134, DIOGO, 15/**12**/**2019**, tttttt, 2]]

```
var funcionarioId ="user1"
var month = "11"
var year = "2019";

var dataFiltered = data.filter(function(item){return item[1] === funcionarioId && 
item[3] === month && 
item[3] === year });
```

The expected results should be:

> [[2, 131, ALEISIO, 13/**11**/**2019**, ggg, 33], [3, 134, DIOGO, 25/**11**/**2019**, gggg, 2]]

Comment: Can you clarify if you are dealing with an array, or a string?  Because the "array" generated you are providing is not syntatically correct.  There are no quotes around the strings and dates.

Comment: `item[3]` is a complete "date". How is `item[3] === month && item[3] === year` supposed to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that will get the required data:

```
var funcionarioId = '134';
var month = "11"
var year = "2019";

var filteredData = data.filter(function(item) {
var items = item[3].split('/');
return items[1] === month &&
       items[2] === year &&
       item[1] == funcionarioId
});
```

Comment: You are correct ,My bad. I meant to also filter by the user Id which is position 2 in the array. For examplo user = "134". Sorry about that!
So my result would be:
[3, 134, DIOGO, 25/11/2019, gggg, 2]

Comment: Answer modified accordingly :)

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Andreas, thank you for the suggestion and I'm in agreement. The code above breacks up the string date dd/mm/yyyy in to Three parts var items = item[3].split('/'); and that allows me to filter the month and year separately. In my real app I also added other components to be filter by like the item[1] == funcionarioId. You guys are super cool!